# How can three workbooks be sent as a single PDF document at the touch of a button as an e-mail attachment without saving locally?

Tags: excel, vba, outlook

Unfortunately, I am still very new to VBA. With my current code, I want to combine three documents into one PDF and send it via email without saving. With the current code, only one document can be sent via email.

I am not able to add more worksheets in this area (Sheet2, Sheet3).

```
    strPath = ActiveWorkbook.Path & Application.PathSeparator & "Sheet1"
    Worksheets("Sheet1").ExportAsFixedFormat xlTypePDF, strPath
    Set emailApplication = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
```

Does anyone have any ideas?

```
Sub Email_From_Excel_Sheet1()
    Dim emailApplication As Object
    Dim emailItem As Object
    Dim strPath As String
    strPath = ActiveWorkbook.Path & Application.PathSeparator & "Sheet1"
    Worksheets("Sheet1").ExportAsFixedFormat xlTypePDF, strPath
    Set emailApplication = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
    Set emailItem = emailApplication.CreateItem(0)
    emailItem.To = Range("X24")
    emailItem.CC = Range("Y24")
    emailItem.Subject = "Sheet1"
    emailItem.Body = "Please find attached the current statement."
    emailItem.Attachments.Add strPath
    emailItem.Display
    Set emailItem = Nothing
    Set emailApplication = Nothing
End Sub
```

I have tried to list the individual worksheets with a comma or enumerate them. I am currently using the following code to generate the PDFs, which I am unable to add as an attachment.

```
Sub Button1_Click()
Dim emailApplication As Object
Dim emailItem As Object
Dim iSheets As Variant
Set iSheet = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")
iSheets = Array("Sheet1", "Sheet2", "Sheet3")
ThisWorkbook.Sheets(iSheets).PrintOut
End Sub
```

Comment: `ThisWorkbook.Sheets(Array("Sheet1", "Sheet2", "Sheet3)).Select`, `ActiveSheet.ExportAsFixedFormat xlTypePDF, strPath`

Comment: Didn't you already ask this earlier today?